If $M$ is a finitely generated module and $\operatorname{pd}(M) = n < \infty$, then is there a finitely generated projective resolution of $M$?
Let $R$ be a ring with unity, and let $M$ be a finitely generated left module over $R$ with projective dimension $\operatorname{pd}(M)=n<\infty$.
Is there a projective resolution of $M$ of the form
$$0\to P_n\to P_{n-1}\to\cdots\to P_1\to P_0\to M\to 0,$$
such that $P_1,\cdots, P_n$ are all finitely generated projective modules?
What about when $M$ is finitely generated but $\operatorname{pd}(M)=\infty$?
When $\operatorname{pd}(M)=\infty$, there should be a counterexample. Let $R := k[x_1, x_2, \cdots]$ be a ring with infinitely many indeterminates over a field $k$. The module $k$ is finitely generated over $R$, but $\operatorname{pd}(k)=\infty$. Consequently, we do not have a projective resolution of $k$ consisting of finitely generated projective modules.

If $ R $ is a left Noetherian ring, then the answers to the above two questions are yes.

The following is a counterexample to the first question.
Let $ R = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \mathbb{Q}\end{bmatrix} $ and $ M = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{Q} \\ \mathbb{Q} \end{bmatrix} / \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $. The following is a projective resolution of $ M $:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
0 \to K \to \left[\begin{array}{c} \mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Q})} \\ 0 \end{array}\right] \to \left[\begin{array}{c} \mathbb{Q} \\ \mathbb{Q} \end{array}\right] \xrightarrow{f} M \to 0\ ,\\
 \searrow \quad \nearrow \\
\left[\begin{array}{c} \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \end{array}\right]
\end{array}
$$
where $ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ is the kernel of the map $ f $, and it is easy to see that $ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ is a superfluous submodule of $ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{Q} \\ \mathbb{Q} \end{bmatrix} $, so $ f $ is a projective cover map of $ M $. Furthermore, $ \mathbb{Q} $ is not finitely generated over $ \mathbb{Z} $ and $ \operatorname{pd}(_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}) = 1 $.
So we can conclude that $ \operatorname{pd}(M) = 2 $ and $ M $ does not have a projective resolution consisting of finitely generated projective modules.
